# Rails 3 ActiveRecord save() Method and Autoincrement Primary Key Fields

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I migrated a Rails site that was running on 2.2.2 to Rails 3.1.

I noticed now, on Rails 3 the save() calls (INSERTS) that used to work in 2.2.2 don't in 3.1

The id field in the database is a primary key so it has the following properties:

not null 
auto-increment

[image]

Now, when the save() method runs on these tables, I get:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

Hmm so I looked at the generated SQL that the save() creates and indeed it's including the id field in the column list and assigning it nil:

```
   PG::Error: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
: INSERT INTO "server_updates" ("action", "created_at", "field_number", "id", "status", "table_number", "value") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"
```

So, my question is how do I get ActiveRecord to not include the id column when it generates the SQL from a save() call?

I certainly don't want to remove the NOT NULL rule from the column nor do I want to rewrite all of these save() calls with raw SQL queries.

Adding `set_primary_key "id"` to the models fixes this issue but seems really messy and un-rails/ruby to me

What do you all do to work around this?

Thanks for helping

Here is one of the models that is getting the error:

```
class ServerUpdate < ActiveRecord::Base



   def ServerUpdate.run_code code
     su = ServerUpdate.new
     su.action = 3 # run code
     su.value = code
     su.status = 1
     su.save
   end

   def ServerUpdate.new_insert_for_table table
      su = ServerUpdate.new
      su.action = 1  # Create New Record
      su.table_number = table.to_i
      su.save
      return su
   end



   def ServerUpdate.new_update_for_table_where_field_equals_value table, field, value
      su = ServerUpdate.new
      su.action = 2  # Update Record
      su.table_number = table.to_i
      su.field_number = field.to_i
      su.value = value.to_s
      su.status = 1 ## This used to be in process() method below
      su.save
      return su
   end

   def ServerUpdate.new_delete_for_table_where_field_equals_value table, field, value
      su = ServerUpdate.new
      su.action = 999  # Delete Record
      su.table_number = table.to_i
      su.field_number = field.to_i
      su.value = value.to_s
      su.save
      return su
   end

   def set_value_for_field value, field, behavior=0
      sui = ServerUpdateItem.new




      sui.server_update_id = self.id
      sui.field_number = field.to_i
      sui.value = value.to_s

      b = 0
      b = 1 if behavior == "prepend" or behavior == 1
      b = 2 if behavior == "append" or behavior == 2
      sui.behavior = b


      sui.save
   end

   def process
      We are now setting status=1 in method:  
      ServerUpdate.new_update_for_table_where_field_equals_value table, field, value
     self.status = 1
     self.save
   end

end
```

Comment: can you post the code for your model?

Comment: ActiveRecord should not include the id column in the insert statement. And usually it doesn't do that. We need more of your code, to find the problem.

Comment: It looks like your id isn't designated as a primary key.  Promote your index on id to an actual primary key, http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9219

Comment: I posted the model code above

Comment: Adding set_primary_key "id" to the models fixes this issue but seems really messy and unnecessary to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `set_primary_key "id"` to the models fixes this issue but seems really messy and unnecessary to me